# Finding AngularJS service provider

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a Jasmine test for an AngularJS service.

I am injecting the required modules but I get the following error:

```
  Message:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module routing due to:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ConfigServiceProvider
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr says that there is an unresolved dependency but I'm a little lost as the routing module contains the only references to ConfigServiceProvider. Do I need to include a module that provides ConfigService? If I do, how do I find which module provides a specific service in AngularJS?

Comment: Your dependency injection may be misspelled. would you please add  your code here.

Comment: @ChamindaJayanathUdawatte which code specifically?

Comment: the code segment where you injection happens

Comment: @ChamindaJayanathUdawatte I just have ```var $injector = window.angular.injector(['ng', 'ui.router', 'routing', 'pages']);``` in my test.